# Unable to get the full match in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the complete Github url from text. But it returns only the first match and not the complete URL. I tested my regex on https://pythex.org/ and its shows the correct match result.

[image]

```
test = 'https://www.github.com/whoisthere'
GITHUB_PATTERN = r"(http(s?):\/\/|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.|[github])[github\/~\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/~\-_,&=\?\.;]+[^\.,\s<]"
GITHUB_REGEX = re.compile(GITHUB_PATTERN,re.IGNORECASE)
github_regex_result = re.findall(GITHUB_REGEX,test)

if len(github_regex_result) > 0:
    print("GITHUB : {}".format(github_regex_result[0]))
else:
    print(None)
```

It returns me the following

```
GITHUB : ('https://', 's')
```

While I am trying to get the complete url like

```
GITHUB : ('https://www.github.com/whoisthere')
```

New screenshot of issue
[image]

Comment: Change all capturing groups to non-capturing.

Comment: Here is the updated regex - GITHUB_PATTERN = r"(?:http(s?):\/\/|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.|[github])[github\/~\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/~\-_,&=\?\.;]+[^\.,\s<]"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew While this issue is fixed, but due to boolean OR, it ignores the github in the URL, how can I fix this

Comment: What boolean OR?

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot. When i search for twitter, it finds the other urls as well

Comment: `[twitter]` matches a single letter out of the set: `t`, `w`, `i`, `e`, `r`. You need to write it without `[...]`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Got that fixed